# How to change the colour of highlighted item in a listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to change the colour of the selected item of my ListBox. It always seems to be a light blue. I Have tried changing the foreground colour of the item when selected item is changed, this has no effect. I am using WP7  Any advice is apreciated.

EDIT: I want to change the text colour of the selected item.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470471/windows-phone-7-highlight-selected-listbox-item

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Option1:

```
ListBoxItem lbi1 = (ListBoxItem)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0));
lbi1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 45, 23, 45));
```

Option2:

```
ListBoxItem lbi2 = (ListBoxItem)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem));

lbi2.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted the text colour not the background colour to change. I wasn't very clear on my post.

Comment: @Tom But shouldn't you be able to work out what to do yourself now, with the above code? For instance, you could take a look at the ListBoxItem class documentation.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry. I misread the question. Updated! I changed `Background` to `Foreground` in both samples.