# How to access controls inside a LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector and use binding.

When the user selects an Item in LongListSelector, I handle the `SelectionChanged` event of it and access it this way:

```
var selectedItem = MyListSelector.SelectedItem as NumbersViewModel;
```

But I want to change background color of that `StackPanel` which this selected item is inside it and add a TextBlock beside it:

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            .
            .
            .
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I do this type of works on LongListSelector?

(It's a WP8 app)

Comment: Changed visual states of the LongListSelector style. Not required to take the stackpanel from  selected item Refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470471/windows-phone-7-highlight-selected-listbox-item

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the background of the stackpanel to a brush which can be added as a property in your NumbersViewModel. Also you can add the textblock inside the template and bind it's visibility to a boolean property inside your NumbersViewModel.

You can set the value of those properties in your selectionchanged event