# LongListSelector - нow to highlight the selected item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, highlight, selecteditem

I am working on Windows Phone 8. When i tap on the items i need to highlight selected item. I use the LongListSelector with DataTemplate.

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="mySelector">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Image Source="{Binding MyImage/>


            <TextBlock   Grid.Column="1"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"                              
                         Text="{Binding Caption}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            </TextBlock>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

   .....

    <phone:LongListSelector Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"  />
```

I watched this example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444. There are two ways - use user control(I do not fit) and search for child elements(I can not find my TextBlock). I need a change in the allocation of color foreground in textblock. Give a simple way to do this.

Comment: You may take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3470471/2681948) or [that one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/c61ba700-e792-4ad2-be4a-cfd4f829452b/longlistselector-highlight-selected-items).

Answer (score 1):

I had once tried using Visual trees and drilling to the specific selected item and changing the background color of the grid inside the data template. 
What i observed was that, the larger is the number of items in the LongListSelector, longer is the time taken to highlight the item. A few times i had also seen the screen going white if i select an item and the resuming to original content with the selected item after say 2 to 3 seconds which was BAD. That time i had switched to a ListBox which worked fine for any number of entries in the List. That can't be a solution though, but thats what i had experienced about LongListSelectors and coloring the selected item.